# Calling templated method of templated member

Tags: c++, templates

I have this code, which doesn't compile (EDIT: compiled in VC, but not in GCC):

```
template<int N>
struct List
{
   template <class C>
   void clear() { }
};

template <int L>
class Test
{
public:
    List<L> list; // <--This line
    void method()
    {
       list.clear<int>(); // <-- Compile error here:  error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’

    }
};
```

How can I make it work? It seems the compiler (gcc) doesn't understand the context, because if in the marked line I replace L with a number, like List<1> list;
then it compiles fine.

Comment: I compiled it as it is. How are you instantiating `Test`? I am using VS.

Comment: Compile fails even if I don't instantiate it, I instantiate it as Test<1> t; What compiler did you use?

Comment: Just tried in VC, indeed it compiles there, so it's GCC related.

Comment: @AlexanderVassilev: No, it is actually MSVC-related. It is **wrong** to accept it.

Comment: @RakibulHasan: Visual C++ accepts a lot of things it shouldn't. This is one of them. It is always dangerous trying to say something authoritative about C++ testing it in Visual C++.

Comment: I have skimmed through  Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords but didn't find a solution for this particular situation, maybe I didn't read carefully enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate `List` with a template argument of `Test`, it becomes a *dependent template*. The compiler can't instantiate it when parsing `Test`, because it does not know value of `L` yet and for all it knows `List` might be specialized differently for different values of `L`. So the compiler can't be sure `clear` is a template and gets confused. You have to add the `template` keyword to disambiguate it like:

```
list.template clear<int>();
//   ^^^^^^^^ here just before the dependent template
```

When you replace `L` with `1`, the template no longer depends on parameters of the enclosing template, so the compiler instantiates and sees `clear` is a template and does not need the disambiguation.

All members of dependent templates need to be disambiguated. The compiler always assumes they are values (function or data), so types have to be disambiguated with `typename` and templates with `template`.

This use of `template` keyword is part of the specification. MSVC can parse many cases, including this one, without it, but it is a MSVC *extension*. Gcc is correct in requiring the `template` keyword here.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/613132/201725) for exhaustive discussion.

Comment: Accepted this as answer because it's most detailed. I suspected it's because type List<L> is unknown at this point, and have tried to use 'template' keyword, but couldn't find the right syntax for this case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `template` keyword before `clear` to help compiler:

```
list.template clear<int>();
     ~~~~~~~~
```